# Why Matlab2tikz can't show figures with categorial data?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, scatter-plot, bubble-chart, tikz

I plotted a bubble chart using scatter plot in Matlab with text lables on x axis and integer numbers on y axis. The bubble sizes are also considered as integer numbers. I included both code and figure of my chart. When I try to transform the figure to tikz using "matlab2tikz" library, I see the following error:
"Error using categorical/cat (line 69): Can not concatenate a double array and a categorical array".
I don't have any double numbers in my values. How can I transform this figure to tikz format?

```
    x = ["C","A", "P", "K"]; %x lables
x1=categorical(x);

y = [33,68,200,14];% values
y1 = [48,177,200,16];
y2=[6,6,200,3];

sz = [35,7, 10, 56];%Bubble sizes
sz1=[25,7, 30, 53];
sz2=[44, 8,4,10];

scatter(x1,y,sz,'g','LineWidth',2);
hold on
scatter(x1,y1,sz1,'b','LineWidth',2);
hold on
scatter(x1,y2,sz2,'r','LineWidth',2);
hold off

legend({'y = Method1','y = Method2', 'y = Method3'},'Location','north');
title('NewModel');
ylabel('%Value');
saveas(gcf,'test.png');
```

[image: Bubble Chart]

Answer (score 0):

You *do* have double numbers. `y`, `y1` and `y2` are double whereas `x1` is categorical which is why you are getting that error.

For your case, the error can be fixed by changing the square brackets to curly brackets in line 4052. i.e. change:

```
data = [xData(:), yData(:)];   %line 4052 of matlab2tikz.m
```

to:

```
data = {xData(:), yData(:)};
```

The reason is what the error message says. You have categorical `xData` and double `yData`. These cannot be concatenated into a regular array. A cell array is for combining different types of data.

---

Similarly,

```
data=applyHgTransform(m2t,[xData(:), yData(:), zData(:)]); %line 4056 of matlab2tikz.m
```

should be modified to the following if you are plotting in 3D and have mixed data type:

```
data=applyHgTransform(m2t,{xData(:), yData(:), zData(:)});
```